# How to implement bitwise of 3-states bit operators to any-size of memory while maximizing size effectivity?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I can use 2 bits to every 3-states bit to implement it, [00 - first, 10 - second, 11\01 - third], but when the second bit is enabled then the first one is useless. In theory there's implementation that will outperform this method (The 2 bits I mentioned) in size by 37%. (Which is `1-log3(2)`)

The code I already tried:

```
#define uint unsigned int

uint set( uint x, uint place, uint value ) {
    double result = ( double )x;
    result /= pow( 3, place );
    result += value - ( ( uint )result ) % 3;
    return result * pow( 3, place );
}
uint get( uint x, uint place ) {
    return ( ( uint )( ( ( double )x ) / pow( 3, place ) ) ) % 3;
}

int main( ) {
    uint s = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
        s = set( s, i, i % 3 );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
        printf( "get( s, %d ) -> %u\n", i, get( s, i ) );
}
```

Which prints:

```
get( s, 0 ) -> 0
get( s, 1 ) -> 1
get( s, 2 ) -> 2
get( s, 3 ) -> 0
...
get( s, 16 ) -> 1
get( s, 17 ) -> 2
get( s, 18 ) -> 0
get( s, 19 ) -> 1
```

This method saves 20% in size. (`1-32/40` - 40 bits is required to do it with the first method I mentioned) In theory when the capacity grows the effectivity grows too. (Towards 37% of course)

How I can implement similar 3-states bitwise method to data of any-size and to maximize size effectivity? If I will use the data as array of `uint`s and use this method on them, I will only get 20% effectivity. (Or lower if the data's size isn't multiplied by 4)

NOTE: The only thing I need is size effectivity, I don't care about speed performance. (Well except if you choose to use `BigInteger` instead of `uint`)

Comment: Bit fiddling and pow(floating point) is no good choice, I think. (Honestly, you need 2 bits and waste on bit of information)

Comment: @DieterLücking I know but towards 1GB of data, it's a waste. (My question is how to make it in the most effective way of size) It's a bit the wrong method to do things as such, but it works. (If I could do anything similar to long data, like choosing the right bits to manipulate and etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`log32` is irrelevant.

The maximal possible efficiency for representing 3-valued units is `log23` bits per unit, and the compression from 2 bits per unit is `(2-log23))/2`, which is roughly 20.75%. So 20% is pretty good.

You shouldn't use `pow` for integer exponentiation; aside from being slow, it is sometimes off by 1ULP which can be enough to make it off by 1 once you coerce it to an integer. But there's no need for all that work either; you can compress five 3-state values into a byte (`35 = 243 < 256`), and its straightforward to build a lookup table with 256 entries, one for each possible byte value.

With the LUT, you can extract a 3-state value from a large vector:

```
/* All error checking omitted */
uint8_t LUT[243][5] = { {0,0,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0,0}, ... };
uint8_t extract(const uint8_t* data, int offset) {
  return LUT[data[offset/5]][offset%5];
}
```

By the way, if a 1215-byte lookup-table is to be considered "big" (which seems odd, given that you're talking about a data vector of 1GB), it's easy enough to compress it by a factor of 4, although it complicates the table construction

```
/* All error checking omitted */
uint8_t LUT[] = { /* Left as an exercise */ };
uint8_t extract(const uint8_t* data, unsigned offset) {
  unsigned index = data[offset/5] * 5 + offset % 5;
  return (LUT[index / 4] >> (2 * (index % 4))) & 3;
}
```

Comment: You may explain the second code. It took a bit to understand the first one too.

Answer (score 4):

In additional to rici's answer I want to post the code I did, which can help too: (simplified one)

```
uint8_t ft[ 5 ] = { 1, 3, 3 * 3, 3 * 3 * 3, 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 };
void set( uint8_t *data, int offset, int value ) {
    uint8_t t1 = data[ offset / 5 ], t2 = ft[ offset % 5 ], u8 = t1 / t2;
    u8 += value - u8 % 3;
    data[ offset / 5 ] = t1 + ( u8 - t1 / t2 )*t2;
}
uint8_t get( uint8_t *data, int offset ) {
    return data[ offset / 5 ] / ft[ offset % 5 ] % 3;
}
```

Instead of the big look up table, I re-implemented the `pow` method just safer and faster one, and added `set` function too.